# For any $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, if $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$ and $\mathbb E|Xf(Y)|<\infty$ then $\mathbb E[f(Y)X|Y]=f(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> For any $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, if $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$ and $\mathbb E|Xf(Y)|<\infty$ then $$\mathbb E[f(Y)X|Y]=f(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]$$

**Definition:** For a random variables $X\in\mathbb R^{d_1}$ and $Y\in\mathbb R^{d_2}$, we define a conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$ by any random variable $Z$ satisfying:

- there exists $g:\mathbb R^{d_2}\rightarrow\mathbb R^{d_1}$ such that $Z=g(Y)$ and
- $\mathbb E\left[Z\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{Y\in A\}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[X\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{Y\in A\}}\right]$ for all $A\subseteq \mathbb R^{d_2}$

But I couldn't manage to prove this using this definition, like how to start?

### Updated

Let $Z=f(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]$ and consider any $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ then,

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Z\unicode{x1D7D9}_{Y\in A}] &= \mathbb E[f(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]\unicode{x1D7D9}_{Y\in A}] \\
&= \mathbb E[h(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]]
\end{align}

Where, $h(Y)=f(Y)\unicode{x1D7D9}_{Y\in A}$. Now I am lost. I think I need to think about $f(Y)$ and try to split it in several cases, but couldn't manage how.

Comment: From the definition of conditional expectation it follows that got any function $g(Y)$ for which $|Xg(Y|\in L_1(\mathbb{P})$, $E[g(Y)X]=E[g(Y)E[X|Y]]$. Tarts with simple functions, then approximates positive functions by monotone sequence of step functions and use monotone convergence. The rest is by linearity.

Comment: Could you redirect me the prove that **Any function $g(Y)$ for which $|Xg(Y)|\in L_1(\mathbb P),\mathbb E[g(Y)X]=\mathbb E[g(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]]$**. And could you give some intuition like why its true. And what is $L_1(\mathbb P)?$ I am afraid that I couldn't recognize that, OliverDiaz

Comment: Start with a positive function $g$ it is a standard trick in the trade to show that the sequence of simple functions $s_n=\sum^{2^n-1}_{k=0}k2^{-n}\mathbb{1}_{\{k2^{-n}\leq g<(k+1)2^{-n}\}} + 2^n\mathbb{1}_{g>2^n\}}$ define a monotone nondecreasing function converging to $g$. For simple functions the result is trivial. Then used monotone convergence to complete the case of positive functions. The rest follows by linearity.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @OliverDiaz. But maybe I am not that much familiar to complete the answer from your comment. I have started this course recently and I study this by myself. Maybe I have a huge lack of experience in analysis.

Comment: You need to impose condition on $f$. For example, requiring that $f$ is Borel measurable.

Comment: But the question didn't impose that @DannyPak-KeungChan. I add some steps. Could you give me some direction?

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory Do you know this fact: Let $X,Y$ be random variables. If $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
is a sub $\sigma$-algebra and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable,
then $E[XY\mid\mathcal{G}]=YE[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$, provided that $X,Y$
have certain kind of integrability? This is a basic property of conditional
expectation and can be found in every textbook of probability theory.

Comment: Aha, that's a nice property. But my lecture note haven't that. Could you suggest/provide any book/link where I can get that, @DannyPak-KeungChan

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory

Check the section "Basic properties"
Pulling out known factors

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation